# Consultar datos de un campo XML en SQL 2014

Tags: sql, xml

Tengo una tabla XMLData. En su columna Data tengo datos como lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<table>
  <id>{6ebd0af9-9838-47f5-8aad-45cf9d4201f7}</id>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="FechaDev" value="01-August-2017" type="System.DateTime" />
        <column name="Importe" value="100" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="DefaultKey" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="FechaDev" value="01-September-2017" type="System.DateTime" />
        <column name="Importe" value="200" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="DefaultKey" value="2" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="FechaDev" value="01-October-2017" type="System.DateTime" />
        <column name="Importe" value="300" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="DefaultKey" value="3" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
  <key>DefaultKey</key>
  <total>0</total>
  <AddOnKey>0</AddOnKey>
  <data />
  <parameters />
</table>
```

Necesito realizar una consulta que me devuelva por ejemplo, los importes que corresponden a fechas dentro del mes de agosto, pero ya para simplemente listar los datos me veo en problemas.

He probado lo siguiente:

```
select x.ID, 
tabla.columna.value('@FechaDev', 'datetime') as fecha,
tabla.columna.value('@Importe', 'varchar(64)') as importe
from XMLData x
outer apply x.data.nodes('?xml/table/rows/row/columns') as tabla(columna)
```

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error, pues parece que el sistema no identifica bien qué es x.data.nodes...

```
Mens. 9506, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 5
The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.
```

También he probado esto:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SELECT @xml = Data FROM XMLData
SELECT  
       Tabla.Columna.value('FechaDev', 'datetime') AS Fecha,
       Tabla.Columna.value('Importe', 'VARCHAR(64)') AS Importe
FROM   @xml.nodes('//column') Tabla(Columna)
```

Pero tampoco funciona, me da el siguiente error:

```
Mens. 2389, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 16
XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'
```

Obviamente, algo no estoy haciendo bien, cualquier ayuda será muy agradecida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cuanto a la lectura del xml, una posibilidad es "pararnos" en el nodo `//table/rows/row/columns` y por el orden acceder a cada columna de esta forma:

```
SELECT  xmlData.Col.value('(column/@value)[1]','varchar(255)') AS 'FechaDev',
    xmlData.Col.value('(column/@value)[2]','varchar(255)') AS 'Importe',
    xmlData.Col.value('(column/@value)[3]','varchar(255)') AS 'DefaultKey'
    FROM    @XML.nodes('//table/rows/row/columns') xmlData(Col)
    WHERE xmlData.Col.value('(column/@value)[1]','varchar(255)') LIKE '%August%'
```

Ten en cuenta que esto asume que la primer columna es FechaDev, la segunda el Importe, Etc. El filtro es a modo de ejemplo, tal vez te convenga convertir los valores. La Salida final:

```
FechaDev       Importe DefaultKey
============== ======= ==========
01-August-2017 100     1
```

**Nota:** En mi caso no me funciono el encoding
 `utf-16` de `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` tuve que modificarlo a  `utf-8`

Espero te sirva

Comment: Genial, funcionó a las mil maravillas, ni siquiera necesité cambiar el encoding, muchísimas gracias!